# I am working on a summation script for PDF JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

This works fine when all the fields have a value but if a field is empty it acts like a string puting all the values the field. I would like this to sum up all fields even if the field is empty.  This script is being added on the "custom calcuation script" on my total field (Amount on Schedule F_11). Please

```
var v1 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_1a").value;
var v2 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_1b").value;
var v3 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_37").value;
var v4 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_46").value;
var v5 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_2").value;
var v6 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_3b").value;
var v7 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_4b").value;
var v8 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_5a").value;
var v9 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_5c").value;
var v10 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_6b").value;
var v11 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_6d").value;
var v12 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_7").value;
var v13 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_8").value;
var v14 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_8_1").value;
var v15 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_8_2").value;
var v16 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_8_3").value;
var v17 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_8_4").value;
var v18 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_8_5").value;
var v19 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_8_6").value;
var v20 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_8_7").value;




event.value = 
((v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20) 
!==0)? 
(v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20)
:"";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var v1 = getField("Amount on Schedule F_1a").value!="" ? getField("Amount on Schedule F_1a").value : 0 ;
```

This will return '0' if the field is empty but your code is very repetitive you could use a loop to iterate through the values.

Have a look at [ternary operator in js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 0):

You discovered the "feature" of JavaScript to be loosely typed, and assigning the type on the fly.

The value of an empty field is the empty string, and that's what makes JavaScript concatenate the values. You'd have to force the type of the field values to be numbers.

The easiest way would be multiplying the field value with 1; that makes the numbers; however, you'd have to make sure that your users actually enter a numeric value (which you could do by setting the format to "number" in the Field Properties dialog). This would then look like:

```
var v1 = this.getField("Amount on Schedule F_1a").value * 1 ;
```

and so on.

Another option would be to use the Number() method. This would then look like:

```
var v1 = Number(this.getField("Amount on Schedule F_1a").value ;
```

If you want to test the result before displaying it, it might be an idea to sum up into a variable, and then test the variable. If it is 0 (and 0 is not a "legal" value), you would set the result field's value to the empty string, otherwise to the result (and you'd have the possibility of full control over the formatting, using util.printf() .

One last comment: for a productive form, it might be worthwhile to have a look at the field names, and make them more compact, or hierarchical with an ordinal number; in that case, you could loop over the field names, and do the calculations in the loop.